# Some users in git prevent other users to push commits to the remote using git with SSH

Tags: linux, git, permissions, push, sles

We are using git for source code management and own a SLES server which we use as a remote for our git repositories. We access git with SSH, using the *real user names*, not the single git user alternative, which would authenticate through the `authorized_keys` file of the git user.

A while ago, I figured out a problem with pushing to our remote. One user was able to push while another user was not able to push. So I began to analyze, why certain users are not able to push. I finally figured out what the root cause was: A bare repository on the remote always has a directory named `objects`, where commits are finally saved through the push process. This directory contains sub directory with the first two characters of a hash value. If a directory has not been created yet, it is created during a push to the remote.

And here's the mysterious thing about it, I cannot explain to myself: Some users create these directories with permissions `rwxrwsr-x`, while other users create them with `rwxr-swr-x`. As you can see, the set-gid bit is set, which is OK. But I cannot really explain why some users create directories with **group write** permissions while others do not.

The pitfall here is that if user A creates a directory without group write permissions and user B calculates a hash value that begins with the two characters of the already created directory of user A, user B cannot place files (commits) in that same directory, which makes it impossible to push to the remote for user B.

I have already watched out for default umask settings, that are probably different, but could not find different settings. All users on our SLES server have the default mask `0022`, which will result in files being created with `rw-r--r--` and directories with `rwxr-xr-x`. And this is the second mystery: Why do some users create directories in git with `rwxrwsr-x` (which is correct for git and intended), despite of the umask `0022`?

Has anyone hints for me for further troubleshooting? What I want to achieve is that users create the `objects` sub directories with `rwxrwsr-x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
git config core.sharedRepository 0660
```

at the server repo. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresharedRepository).